# How do I print a Timeseries with year on x-axis and count on the y-axis for a particular category type

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zmNv.png) I want to print a time series in Python where my x-axis has the years which are stored in a variable and has a type `STRING`. My y-axis should print the count at each year for a primary type `category = Drug Narcotics [I am expecting a graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saTHG.jpg)

```html
primary_type_categories      Date1
Drug/Narcotic Violation   05-03-16 21:00
Serious Offenses   05-03-16 21:30
Violent Crimes           05-03-16 18:30
Non-Criminal           05-03-16 22:00
Drug/Narcotic Violation   05-03-16 21:30
```

`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=(df.Date1.dt.year).apply(str) -> Date1 is in Datetime format
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=20,7
b=df['primary_type_categories'].unique().tolist()
c=b[0]


plt.plot((a.groupby(c).agg('count')), c= 'black', ls='--', marker='s', ms=5)
plt.xticks(list(range(0,10)),a, rotation ='vertical')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have a sample df you can share?

Comment: @ScottBoston can you see the df now as I have edited my post

Comment: If you wish to get an answer for your specific question, provide a minimal working example including sample data in a copy/pastable format so others can actually help. As it stands there's a lot of unnecessary code that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the Inconvenience @AlexanderReynolds. Please check the edited post and let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your patience.